# How can you alert the inner html of a clicked div with no id?

Tags: javascript, html, this

In an instance where you are trying to get multiple divs with different contents to alert their contents on click It might be common for them to each have the same class and no unique ids. How can I alert the inner html of a div when clicked if it is only identified by a class name? :
For example :

html

```
<div class='button'> a </div>
<div class='button'> b </div>
<div class='button'> c </div> 
<div class='button'> d </div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    alert(this.innerHTML)
  })
})
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: arrow function event handlers dont capture `this`, Change this line to `item.addEventListener('click', function(event) { `

Comment: Thank you Kunal this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

use `event.target` to get access to the very element you have just clicked :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('click', event => {alert(event.target.innerHTML)
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), the `target` property of `Event` interface will refence the object onto which the event was dispatched.

So you can get the text inside the clicked `div` using `event.target`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    alert(event.target.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class='button'> a </div>
<div class='button'> b </div>
<div class='button'> c </div> 
<div class='button'> d </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case just replacing `this` with `item` would make your snippet work:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    alert(item.innerHTML)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class='button'> a </div>
<div class='button'> b </div>
<div class='button'> c </div>
<div class='button'> d </div>
```

Word of advice: if you are adding interactivity, use "real" `button` elements that are designed for it: you'll get keyboard support and better accessibility overall for free.

Also, you can use single handler attached at some parents of target elements, what is said to be better in certain scenarios:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click',buttonClick);

function buttonClick(event){
  var tgt = event.target;
  if(tgt.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;
  alert( "»" + tgt.innerText + "«");
}
```

```css
button { display: block; }
```

```html
<button> a </button>
<button> b </button>
<button> c </button> 
<button> d </button>
```